# How to check who is locking my OneDrive shared file for editing?

Tags: onedrive

I have an Excel file shared on OneDrive. How can I know who is locking the file without going to the online web Excel version?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is just a fake locking. Try to delete the owner file ~ or $

See this description from Microsoft help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313472/the-document-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-user-error-message-when